# How to execute 5 different ruby files in series

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby and I'm trying to run 5 different files in a folder. I'd like to execute them all in series mean one after another.

the list of my files are:

```
Scripts/aaa. rb

Scripts/bbb. rb

Scripts/ccc. rb

Scripts/ddd. rb

Scripts/eee. rb
```

My script should run the `aaa.rb` first and then rest

Comment: What OS are you on? The easiest is to do this from a batch or shell script. That's what they're there for.

Answer (score 4):

Do as below using [*Dir::chdir*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html#method-c-chdir), [*Dir::glob*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob):

```
Dir.chdir("path/to/the/.rb files") do |path|
  Dir.glob("*.rb").sort.each do |name|
    system("ruby #{name}")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

create another ruby script to run them in order

```
["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"].each do |name|
  system("ruby #{name}.rb") #give the full path of the file here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your OS, you can use a batch file, or a shell script. In either case, that's exactly their purpose. Assuming you have the executable bit set on the files:

On *nix or Mac OS:

```
#!/bin/sh

Scripts/aaa.rb 
Scripts/bbb.rb 
Scripts/ccc.rb
Scripts/ddd.rb 
Scripts/eee.rb
```

as a simplistic script.

For something a bit more "DRY":

```
#!/bin/sh

pushdir Scripts
for i in aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
do
  $i.rb
done
popdir
```

If the executable-bit isn't set, precede the name of the file with the path to your Ruby executable, something like:

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby Scripts/aaa.rb
```

There are a lot of other ways to point to the Ruby executable, so your mileage might vary.